# Check collection exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have this code:

```
@foreach($subCategories as $subCategory)
  <tr data-id="{{ $subCategory->id }}" id="{{ $subCategory->id }}" class="sortItem">
    <td class="text-left">
      {!! Str::limit($subCategory->category_name, 80, '...') !!}
      <p class="text-muted"></p>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      @if ($subCategory->enable == 1)
        <span class="label font-weight-bold label-lg label-light-success label-inline">
          <i class="ft-thumbs-up"></i> aktywny
        </span>
      @else
        <span class="label font-weight-bold label-lg label-light-danger label-inline">
          <i class="ft-thumbs-down"></i> nieaktywny
        </span>
      @endif
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <a href="{{ route('subcategory.index', ['parentId'=>$subCategory->id]) }}" class="badge badge-primary badge-md h-30px">
        <i class="ft-aperture"></i> Rozwiń
      </a>
      <a href="{{ route('subcategory.edit', ['id'=>$subCategory->id]) }}" class="badge badge-info badge-md h-30px">
        <i class="ft-aperture"></i> Edytuj
      </a>
      <form method="post" action="{{ route('subcategory.destroy', ['id'=>$subCategory->id, 'parentId'=>$parentId]) }}" class="d-inline-block" onSubmit="showAlert();{return false;}">
        @method('DELETE')
        {{ csrf_field()  }}
        <input type="submit" class="removeBtn" value="Usuń">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Sometimes there is an error in the above code:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/resources/views/admin/categories/subcategory_list.blade.php)

When I debug, problem is when in my $subCategory I have:

```
App\Models\Category {#487 ▼
  #quarded: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:11 [▶]
  +timestamps: false
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "categories"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▶]
  #original: array:12 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #pending: null
  #moved: false
}
```

When I have in debug:

```
Kalnoy\Nestedset\Collection {#487 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Category {#1423 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Category {#1422 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Category {#1426 ▶}
  ]
}
```

This code work fine.

How can I secure my foreach function so that it doesn't display an error?

Comment: I guess the simplest thing is to check the id ```@if (isset($model->id))```

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, a loop should not return elements that are `NULL`

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? None of the `$subCategory->id` calls would cause that error. If each `$subCategory` is an instance of your `Category` model, it is an object, and `->id` would either return the `id` or `null`. The main time you see this error is when trying to access a property (like `->id`) on an `array` (`['id']`) or `null` (`->id` and `['id']` would both fail)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can check if the $subCategories variable has a count grather than 0

```
@if($subCategories->count())
here goes your loop
@endif
```

The laravel collection instance has a method named [count](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_count). You can check with it the length of the collection and loop over it only if it has atleast 1 result.

if `$subCategories->count()` returns 0 it will interpretate it as `FALSE` and It won't enter the code below. As soon the `$subCategories->count()` is greather than 0 it will be true and execute the code in the if statement. If you need more explanation feel free to ask.

Comment: If counting elements returns zero elements, the loop is not entered

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to wrap an `@foreach()` with an `@if(count(...))` unless you need to do something different if it is empty. And even then, you can use a `@forelse(...) @empty ... @endforelse` instead: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops